# String phrase ends at space?

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

I am wringing a simple code to learn more about string. When I ran my code it would not print my last name. Can someone explain why? I used string phrase to store it and it only appears to have stored my first name. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    cout << "Exercise 3B" << endl;
    cout << "Kaitlin Stevers" << endl;
    cout << "String arrays" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    char greeting[26];
    cout << "Please enter a greeting: " << endl;
    cin >> greeting;
    cout << "The greeting you entered was: " << greeting << endl;
    string phrase;
    cout << "Enter your full name " << endl;
    cin >> phrase;
    cout << greeting << ", how are you today " << phrase << "?" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Are you sure you do not see the desired output?

Comment: Yes. Maybe my compiler doesn't have a file it needs to do string. Will you post a picture of your out put please.

Comment: In my compiler the word string doesn't even light up to another color. If it was working right wouldn't it?

Comment: Terminology warning: You have compiler mixed up with text editor. The editor displays and allows you to edit the source code. The compiler turns the source code into object code (and the linker turns object code into an executable program). The compiler doesn't make words light up; if you've written the source code correctly it doesn't show you anything more than a nice "All done" type message.

Comment: Ahh, got you! Thanks for telling me that because I've actually been wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I used string phrase to store it and it only appears to have stored my first name.

That makes sense.

```
cin >> phrase;
```

will stop reading when it encounters a whitespace character in the input.

To read the full name you can use one of the following approaches.

1. Use two calls to `cin >>`.

   ```
   std::string first_name;
   std::string last_name;
   cin >> first_name >> last_name;
   ```
2. Use `getline` to read the entire line. `getline` will read everything in a a line, including whitespace characters.

   ```
   getline(cin, phrase);
   ```

Comment: Thank you. I figured maybe that was the case!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `cin >> phrase;`, it only reads the string up to the first non-space character. If you want to include spaces in your name, best goes with `getline(cin,phrase);`.

IMPORTANT: `getline()` will reads whatever it is in the stream buffer up to the first `\n`. It means that when you enter `cin >> greeting;`, if you hit ENTER, `getline()` will read everything before that `\n` that is not already read, which is NOTHING into your `phrase` variable, making it an empty string. An easy way out is to call `getline()` twice. E.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    cout << "Exercise 3B" << endl;
    cout << "Kaitlin Stevers" << endl;
    cout << "String arrays" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    char greeting[26];
    cout << "Please enter a greeting: " << endl;
    cin >> greeting;  //IMPORTANT: THIS ASSUME THAT GREETING IS A SINGLE WORD (NO SPACES)
    cout << "The greeting you entered was: " << greeting << endl;
    string phrase;
    cout << "Enter your full name " << endl;
    string rubbish_to_be_ignored;
    getline(cin,rubbish_to_be_ignored); //this is going to read nothing
    getline(cin, phrase); // read the actual name (first name and all)
    cout << greeting << ", how are you today " << phrase << "?" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Assuming you store that code in the file stackoverflow.cpp. Sample run:

```
Chip Chip@04:26:00:~ >>>  g++ stackoverflow.cpp -o a.out
Chip Chip@04:26:33:~ >>>  ./a.out
Exercise 3B
Kaitlin Stevers
String arrays


Please enter a greeting: 
Hello  
The greeting you entered was: Hello
Enter your full name 
Kaitlin Stevers
Hello, how are you today Kaitlin Stevers?
```

Tested on ubuntu 14.04